# serialport communication using Node.js - packaging and sending 8-bit binary data

Tags: node.js, binary, serial-port, hex, ascii

I’ doing a POC with serialport communication using Node.js
I’m connected to cellular modem via serial port and the target is to transmit the data over UDP.
My scripts collects data from the modem (i.e. IMEI number, 15 digit) in a form of String. Then I transmit the data like:

```
var IMEI = “354345678654561”;
serialPort.write(IMEI + '\r');
```

On modem side, each digit is received as ASCII text, coded as single byte (8-bit binary) and transmited as 15 bytes over the air. On the server side I receive 33 35 34…
But I wish to send binary value of the String “1 0100 0010 0100 0110 1000 1000 0100 1101 1100 1100 0110 0001” which be 7 bytes in total.

Tried the `Buffer.from()` and played with Arrays but no real success.

Any help is appreciated

figured out that doing

```
BUF1[0] = 0x27;
BUF1[1] = 0x0F;
serialPort.write(BUF1, 0,);
serialPort.write(BUF1, 1,);
```

would actually work